# Javascript obects of objects to one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation, javascript-objects

Can someone please help me with some code on how to turn an array of objects to a single array as i have a setInterval that calls the api after every 2 min and pushes the result to the variable prod, now the variable has become an array of objects i just want to make it a single array. This is how prod looks like at the moment

```
var prod = [
    [{
        "order_id": "283828",
        "product_id": "126354",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "customer_note": "",
        "out_of_stock": "pick_specific_replacement",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "317",
        "price": "98.99"
    }],
    [{
        "order_id": "283828",
        "product_id": "126354",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "customer_note": "",
        "out_of_stock": "pick_specific_replacement",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "317",
        "price": "98.99"
    }]
]
```

i want to turn it into

```
var prod = [
    {
        "order_id": "283828",
        "product_id": "126354",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "customer_note": "",
        "out_of_stock": "pick_specific_replacement",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "317",
        "price": "98.99"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "283828",
        "product_id": "126354",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "customer_note": "",
        "out_of_stock": "pick_specific_replacement",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "317",
        "price": "98.99"
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Post some code, make sure to visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
prod = prod.map(a => a[0]);
```

But rather than patching the result, the root of the problem should be avoided. I assume somewhere in your code you have something like `prod.push(something)`. This should be changed to `prod.push(something[0])`. To be sure, you'll need to share the code that feeds the `prod` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.concat()` with spread syntax:

```js
let data = [
    [{"order_id": "283828", "product_id": "126354", "order_qty": "1", "customer_note": "", "out_of_stock": "pick_specific_replacement", "status": "0", "id": "317", "price": "98.99"}],
    [{"order_id": "283828", "product_id": "126354", "order_qty": "1", "customer_note": "", "out_of_stock": "pick_specific_replacement", "status": "0", "id": "317", "price": "98.99"}]
];

let result = [].concat(...data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Recommend more explanation for why/how that works. *(In the first version, not an edit.)*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing to the array for each API call, concat the result to the array;

```
prod.push(response);
```

Will turn into:

```
prod = prod.concat(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are few different ways to achive that:

Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight):

```js
const data = [[{a: 1}],[{b: 2}]];
const result = data.reduce((r,c) => [...r, ...c])
console.log(result)
```

Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) & [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const data = [[{a: 1}],[{b: 2}]];
const result = data.reduce((r,c) => r.concat(c))
console.log(result)
```

Using only [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const data = [[{a: 1}],[{b: 2}]];
const result = [].concat(...data)
console.log(result)
```

Using [recursion](https://medium.com/functional-javascript/recursion-282a6abbf3c5) with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) to flatten recursively instead of one level only:

```js
const data = [[{a: 1}],[{b: 2}], [[{c: 1}]], [[[{d: 1}]]]];
const flattenDeep = (arr, accumulator = []) =>
   arr.reduce((r,c) => 
   (Array.isArray(c) ? flattenDeep(c, r) : r.push(c), r), accumulator)

console.log(flattenDeep(data))
```

Using lodash [flatten](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatten) & [flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flattenDeep):

```js
const data = [[{a: 1}],[{b: 2}]];
console.log('flatten: ', _.flatten(data))

const data2 = [[{a: 1}],[{b: 2}], [[{c: 1}]], [[[{d: 1}]]]];
console.log('flattenDeep: ', _.flattenDeep(data2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```